# Function that returns a value exactly on the hour every hour

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a function that will return a value exactly on the hour every hour. The code below it what I've got so far but is there a better approach I could take?

```
func main() {
    for {
            t := time.Now()
            if t.Minute() == 00 {
                fmt.Println("Hello World!")
            }
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just sleep for an hour and execute the `fmt.Println()` each time? Then you don't even need the conditional. Not saying that's a "good" approach, but it certainly would require less code than you have, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: What would make it "better"? Are you looking for simpler code, less resource usage, more precise timing, what?

Comment: More precise timing would be my main aim, I want it executing exactly on the hour.

Comment: A better bet would be a time.Ticker, as this fires at the specified time regardless of how long the intervening function calls take.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/HMXnkt-ATa

Answer (score 3):

You can use the time package [AfterFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#AfterFunc) function.

```
time.AfterFunc(time.Hour * 1, func() {
  // Do something!
})
```

It returns a Timer that can be used to cancel the call using its Stop method. The first call you might have to calculate the time remaining till the next hour, so that every invocation is on the hour as you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start the action exactly at minute/second `0`, then truncating to an hour is a bit tricky in [Go](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate).

And the time shifts a bit every time because all guarantees about timing have the condition *at least* (for example `time.Sleep(d)` sleeps at least for `d` duration of time; not exactly `d`).

With these requirements, this code does the task:

```
func main() {
    timer := time.NewTimer(nextDelay())
    for {
        <-timer.C
        timer.Reset(nextDelay())
        time.Sleep(time.Minute * 59) // the task, or you could do more tricks with channels
    }
}

func nextDelay() time.Duration {
    now := time.Now()
    return truncateHour(now).Add(time.Hour).Sub(now)
}

func truncateHour(t time.Time) time.Time {
    t = t.Truncate(time.Minute * 30)
    if t.Minute() > 0 {
        t = t.Add(time.Minute * -1).Truncate(time.Minute * 30)
    }
    return t
}
```

(In [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tIfvCZZczXv))

Comment: short version: `time.NewTimer(time.Now().Truncate(time.Minute).Add(time.Hour).Sub(time.Now()))`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to update to `hour` -> `time.NewTimer(time.Now().Truncate(time.Hour).Add(time.Hour).Sub(time.Now()))`